# Passing a function in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am trying to pass a function to another function to use in its call back, I call the function using...

```
call("login", {email:user,password:pw}, alert(getResponse()));
```

call is defined as:

```
function call(url, p, f){
    $.getJSON(baseUrl + url, p, f(data));
};
```

and getResponse is defined as:

```
function getResponse(d){
    return d.result.success;
};
```

`data` is returned by `getJSON` (see here: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/)

How am I meant to pass `data` to that function?

The function is called, because it hits a break point I set.

When `getResponse` is called though I get `Uncaught ReferenceError: data is not defined`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use

```
call("login", {email:user,password:pw}, function(data){alert(getResponse(data)}));
```

The expression `alert(getResponse())` is the call of the alert function (with `getResponse` called without any parameter, and thus this would throw an error as `d.result` would mean taking `result` from `undefined`), but `function(data){alert(getResponse(data)})` is the definition of a new function taking data as parameter.

Also on a note to that you do not need to have `f(data)` in `$.getJSON(baseUrl + url, p, f(data));` you only require `f`, so you would call `$.getJSON(baseUrl + url, p, f);`

Comment: Sweet as, I knew it would be something simple like that. Just haven't done enough js in my time

Answer (score 1):

The expression `alert(getResponse())` pops an alert and doesn't evaluate to a function but to `undefined`.

You have to pass a function which implementation is alert(getResponse(d)) where d is it's parameter.

Such as the expression `function(d){alert(getResponse(d);}` for example